Getting error when doing npx create-react-app my-react-app
PS C:\Users\ARPIT\Desktop> npx create-react-app my-react-app
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
npm error path C:\Users\ARPIT\Desktop
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ARPIT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-18T09_45_44_534Z-debug-0.log

I tried to change my environment path, reinstalled Node twice and searched for the solution in YouTube.

At this point: simply don't use CRA for new apps. It hasn't been maintained for several years.

First run npm cache clean --force , npm i -g npm-check-updates and then npx create-react-app my-react-app.
Does it work?

If you would like to use react with JS, use the following boilerplate:
Webpack react boilerplate
If you would like to use react with typescript, use the following boilerplate:
Webpack react typescript boilerplate

•   Check and update the system PATH to include C:\WINDOWS\system32.
•   Ensure cmd.exe is present in C:\WINDOWS\system32.
•   Reinstall Node.js to reset PATH settings.
•   Try running the command in a different terminal (PowerShell or Windows Terminal).
•   Review and reset the npm configuration if necessary.
•   Review the detailed log file for more information.
•   Update npm to the latest version.

